# How can I enable second core of my Intel Atom in my Dell mini 910?

Tags: shutdown, multi-core

I did the following trick:
http://junkypc.com/enable-dual-core-processors-ubuntu/
But after that when I was trying to shutdown the system it seemed like shutting down forever so I had to use forced shutdown by holding power. The problem didn't dissappeared so I had to restore the lines "currency=shell" to "none" as it was.

It's shutting down properly. But I'd be really glad if my first netbook with my first Ubuntu would work faster. I have installed 32bit version due to low capacity of my ssd (16gb). Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance and my regards for all linux community :)

Answer (score 2):

Dual core processor are well supported. That tutorial is for old (very old) ubuntu.

To confirm you can run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to get the cpu information.

also you can see how ubuntu is using processor cores by running `system-monitor` (gnome-system-monitor)

[image: gnome-system-monitor]

If you feel your ubuntu is running slow. There are some distros that can help you work flawlessly.

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) & [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) both based on ubuntu but less resource hungry.